How to create a semi circle dounut shape chart in reactjs and tailwind css
I wanted to build a semi-circle donut shape chart using React JS and tailwind CSS as shown in the picture below how to create this type of circle which looks like a semi-circle and has a different color of arrow-like box containing and is separated equally in this container. and this could not be affected by any screen of the website. I am using SVG to create this but it is not implementing correctly How do you make this design with the help of React JS and Tailwind CSS?

const HalfCircleChart = () => {
  const SVG_WIDTH = 400;
  const SVG_HEIGHT = 250;

  const RADIUS = Math.min(SVG_WIDTH, SVG_HEIGHT) / 2 - 50;
  const CENTER_X = SVG_WIDTH / 2;
  const CENTER_Y = SVG_HEIGHT / 2 + RADIUS / 2;

  const NUM_SEGMENTS = 25;

  const angleStep = Math.PI / NUM_SEGMENTS;

  return (
    <>
      <svg width={SVG_WIDTH} height={SVG_HEIGHT}>
        <path
          d={
            `M ${CENTER_X} ${CENTER_Y} ` +
            `L ${CENTER_X - RADIUS} ${CENTER_Y} ` +
            `A ${RADIUS} ${RADIUS} 0 1 1 ${CENTER_X + RADIUS} ${CENTER_Y} ` +
            `Z`
          }
          fill="#f0f0f0"
          stroke="grey"
        />
        {Array.from({ length: NUM_SEGMENTS }).map((_, index) => {
          const startAngle = index * angleStep;
          const endAngle = (index + 1) * angleStep;

          const largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle > Math.PI ? 1 : 0;

          const x1 = CENTER_X + RADIUS * Math.cos(startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
          const y1 = CENTER_Y + RADIUS * Math.sin(startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
          const x2 = CENTER_X + RADIUS * Math.cos(endAngle - Math.PI / 2);
          const y2 = CENTER_Y + RADIUS * Math.sin(endAngle - Math.PI / 2);

          return (
            <path
              key={index}
              d={
                `M ${CENTER_X} ${CENTER_Y} ` +
                `L ${x1} ${y1} ` +
                `A ${RADIUS} ${RADIUS} 0 ${largeArcFlag} 1 ${x2} ${y2} ` +
                `Z`
              }
              fill={`hsl(${(index / NUM_SEGMENTS) * 360}, 70%, 70%)`}
              stroke="white"
            />
          );
        })}
      </svg>
    </>
  );
};


This looks like a straightforward set of elements rotated about a common origin and clipped and colored. Have you tried simple HTML/CSS to create it? We are here to help with specific coding problems rather than code things ab initio. You can edit your question to include whatever code is causing a problem.
